# Cannot Start MYSQL Server Mac

Tags: mysql, macos, pid

I am currently trying to run mysql server on a mac, but the Start MySQL Server from the preferences pane doesn't work, and neither does starting it from the Terminal. I have found a lot of fixes, but none of them work. This is my first time using MySQL, I have very little (just a bit of Java) programming experience, and this is my first StackOverflow post in a long time (please help me learn if I did it incorrectly!).

I installed this version(didn't use brew): mysql-5.7.21-1-macos10.13-x86_64
My machine is 64 bit

What I've tried:

1. Uninstalled and reinstalled MySQL using this process:

> To uninstall MySQL and completely remove it (including all databases) from your Mac do the following:
>
> Open a terminal window Use mysqldump to backup your databases to text
>   files! Stop the database server sudo rm /usr/local/mysql sudo rm -rf
>   /usr/local/mysql* sudo rm -rf /Library/StartupItems/MySQLCOM sudo rm
>   -rf /Library/PreferencePanes/My* edit /etc/hostconfig and remove the line MYSQLCOM=-YES- rm -rf ~/Library/PreferencePanes/My* sudo rm -rf
>   /Library/Receipts/mysql* sudo rm -rf /Library/Receipts/MySQL* sudo rm
>   -rf /private/var/db/receipts/*mysql* https://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/uninstall-mysql-mac-os-x

2. When I open the folder where mysql is installed, I do not have permissions to open the data or keychain folders. So, I decided it was a permissions problem and tried this: [Cannot start Mysql on Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36183404/cannot-start-mysql-on-mac). When I tried to start the server, I got the following error:

> sudo /usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server start Starting MySQL
>   .Logging to '/usr/local/mysql/data/XXXXs-MacBook-Air.local.err'.
>   /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld_safe: line 198:  7892 Trace/BPT trap: 5
>   nohup /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld --basedir=/usr/local/mysql
>   --datadir=/usr/local/mysql/data --plugin-dir=/usr/local/mysql/lib/plugin --user=mysql --log-error=XXXXs-MacBook-Air.local.err --pid-file=/usr/local/mysql/data/XXXXs-MacBook-Air.local.pid < /dev/null > /dev/null 2>&1  **ERROR! The server quit without updating
>   PID file** (/usr/local/mysql/data/XXXXs-MacBook-Air.local.pid).

3. Tried to check the admin version and got the following error:

> XXXXs-MacBook-Air:mysql XXXX$ bin/mysqladmin version mysqladmin:
>   connect to server at 'localhost' failed error: 'Can't connect to local
>   MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)' Check that mysqld
>   is running and that the socket: '/tmp/mysql.sock' exists!

4. Tried to open /temp/mysql.sock from the command line and got that it does not exist
5. Tried this:

> XXXXs-MacBook-Air:mysql XXXX$ % mysqladmin variables
>   -bash: fg: %: no such job XXXXs-MacBook-Air:mysql XXXX$ mysqladmin variables
>   -bash: mysqladmin: command not found

6. Tried removing my.cnf per [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/748478/cannot-find-mysql-sock) and restarted the server

> sudo rm -rf /etc/my.cnf
>   sudo /usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server start

7. Tried these instructions [MySql server startup error 'The server quit without updating PID file '](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4963171/mysql-server-startup-error-the-server-quit-without-updating-pid-file)

> XXXXs-MacBook-Air:mysql XXXX$ ps -ef | grep mysql   501  9173
>   549   0 11:54PM ttys000    0:00.01 grep mysql
>   XXXXs-MacBook-Air:mysql XXXX$ kill -9 PID
>   -bash: kill: PID: arguments must be process or job IDs XXXXs-MacBook-Air:mysql XXXX$ ls -laF /usr/local/var/mysql/ ls:
>   /usr/local/var/mysql/: No such file or directory
>   XXXXs-MacBook-Air:mysql XXXX$ ls -laF /usr/local/mysql lrwxr-xr-x 
>   1 root  wheel  30 Apr  4 22:44 /usr/local/mysql@ ->
>   mysql-5.7.21-macos10.13-x86_64 XXXXs-MacBook-Air:mysql XXXX$ sudo
>   chown -R mysql /usr/local/var/mysql/ Password: chown:
>   /usr/local/var/mysql/: No such file or directory
>   XXXXs-MacBook-Air:mysql XXXX$ sudo chown -R mysql /usr/local/mysql
>   XXXXes-MacBook-Air:mysql XXXX$ sudo
>   /usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server start Starting MySQL
>   .Logging to '/usr/local/mysql/data/XXXXs-MacBook-Air.local.err'.
>   /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld_safe: line 198:  9327 Trace/BPT trap: 5
>   nohup /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld --basedir=/usr/local/mysql
>   --datadir=/usr/local/mysql/data --plugin-dir=/usr/local/mysql/lib/plugin --user=mysql --log-error=XXXXs-MacBook-Air.local.err --pid-file=/usr/local/mysql/data/XXXXs-MacBook-Air.local.pid < /dev/null > /dev/null 2>&1 . ERROR! The server quit without updating
>   PID file (/usr/local/mysql/data/XXXXs-MacBook-Air.local.pid).
>   XXXXs-MacBook-Air:mysql XXXX$ unset TMPDIR
>   XXXXs-MacBook-Air:mysql XXXX$ mysql_install_db --verbose
>   --user=`whoami` --basedir="$(brew --prefix mysql)" --datadir=/usr/local/var/mysql --tmpdir=/tmp
>   -bash: mysql_install_db: command not found

And now I'm back to this error:

> ERROR! The server quit without updating PID file 
>   (/usr/local/mysql/data/XXXXs-MacBook-Air.local.pid).

Please help!

**EDITED: I uninstalled and reinstalled with brew. Using these instructions: http://stefan.magnuson.co/articles/osx/reinstalling-mysql-on-osx-with-homebrew/ Now it works.**

Comment: Uninstall `mysql` and check `/usr/local/mysql/` directory if the binaries still exist.

Comment: Uninstalled mysql. /usr/local/mysql/ doesn't exist

Comment: Try installing now and see if the directory populates??

Comment: It populated. Started the server again and got this: 
 ERROR! The server quit without updating PID file (/usr/local/mysql/data/XXXXs-Air.domain.pid).
XXXXs-Air:~ XXXX$

Comment: Can you check the permissions of ‘/usr/local/mysql/data/XXXXs-Air.domain.pid’ file? Also would like to know if you are seeing errors in error file..

Comment: It says permission denied for that .pid file.

Comment: I can't find the error file

Answer (score 2):

I uninstalled and reinstalled SQL with Homebrew using these instructions: http://stefan.magnuson.co/articles/osx/reinstalling-mysql-on-osx-with-homebrew/ Now it works.

Answer (score 0):

This small diagnosis worked for me in MAC...

open Your Terminal and use the following command to check all the instances or mysql that are currently running in your machine.

```
1) ps -ef | grep mysql
```

If you found any process Id with the above command.

```
2) sudo kill -9 [PID]
```

Where [PID] is the process id next to username

now try restarting mysql again using the mysql server pane or go to terminal and type the following command

```
sudo /usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server start
```